# Showing file permission bits in the modeline?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have found myself switching between Emacs and a shell several times today, just to check the file permissions before saving the file I have open in Emacs.

Needless to say, this is suboptimal and provides ample opportunity for improvement.

I would like to have the modeline show the permission bits, sort of like;

`-:--- .netrc 0600 .... further modeline stuff ....`

The closest I have seen to accomplish this goal is [on the emacs-fu blog](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.dk/2011/08/customizing-mode-line.html), but I would like a more generic solution than just checking whether the file is read only.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played with it a bit and got this to work for me:

```
;; New variable to contain buffer file permission format construct.
(defvar my-mode-line-buffer-permissions
  '(:eval (when (buffer-file-name) (format " %04o" (file-modes (buffer-file-name))))))
;; The variable must be marked as "risky" (see C-h v mode-line-format)
(put 'my-mode-line-buffer-permissions 'risky-local-variable t)
;; And finally add it right after the file name:
(setq-default
 mode-line-buffer-identification
 (append mode-line-buffer-identification (list 'my-mode-line-buffer-permissions)))
```

My mode line now says:

```
-uu-:---F1  .emacs       0644   Top L1     (Emacs-Lisp)--------------
```

Comment: Just perfect! I'm going to do nothing more the rest of the day than open files in emacs and look at the modeline